# Extending an existing object to implement Comparable, in Java

Tags: java, comparable

Currently my issue is that I need to use an existing framework which I am not allowed to change, and the most convenient way to solve my problem is to use Comparable objects. Suppose I have an object Foo, which does not implement Comparable, and I'm not allowed to go in and change it to make it Comparable. My idea was to just use Bar, which extends Foo and implements Comparable.

```
public class Bar extends Foo implements Comparable
{
   public int compareTo( Object o)
   {
      Foo f = (Foo) o;
      if( this.getID() < f.getID() ) return -1;
      else if ( this.getID() == f.getID() ) return 0;
      else return -1;
   }
}
```

But then suppose I get an instance of Foo somewhere. How do I turn it into an instance of Bar? Is there an a recommended alternative solution to this situation?

Comment: Couldn't you just create a constructor for Bar that takes a Foo?

Comment: Will you be creating all the objects, or does the framework create some too?  Do they have a factory for these things that you could extend to make `Bar`s instead of `Foo`s?

Comment: This smells like something that could be solved with the [Decorator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

Comment: Couldn't you also just provide a `Comparator` class that does the comparison?

Comment: @templatetypedef I needed to use Bar in a TreeSet, which seems to require that the objects are comparable.

Comment: @bhh1988- TreeSet can also be configured to use a custom comparator saying how to compare elements.  Isn't this a better option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you absolutely need a Comparable, not a Comparator, use a Decorator (as mentioned by others)

```
public class ComparableFoo implements Comparable<ComparableFoo> {

   final Foo foo;

   public ComparableFoo(Foo foo) {
      this.foo = foo;
   }

   @Override
   public int compareTo(ComparableFoo o) {
      Foo other = o.foo;
      // do comparison here, e.g.
      return foo.getDate().compareTo(other.getDate());
   }

}
```

Note that ComparableFoo need not extend Foo.  In some cases that might be nice, but not a requirement.  If you really want to get at the underlying Foo, you have it in a field, and you could either access that field, or provide a formal accessor.

Comment: This adds another level of indirection though...as Anony-Mousse was saying. I was trying to avoid this option

Comment: @bhh1988  If you have only 10s or even 100s of Foo objects, don't sweat it.  If you have 1000s, and need to do this often, strongly consider using a Comparator.

Answer (score 1):

The decorator pattern will maybe work. It comes however at the cost of additionally boxing objects, so I wouldn't use if you have many objects.

If you can, using a `Comparator` is actually much simpler. In fact, it gives you a couple of *additional* options that you cannot have with `Comparable`, such as defining alternative sort orders.

Also consider using generics. It's not just a toy to make code more complicated, it actually helps preventing a certain type of bugs that can be a pain to discover, because they usually "mostly" work, and then suddenly start failing much later when subclasses are added.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

You could sort classes using the Java Collections framework and your Comparator.

Comment: Note that he nowhere said that he was sorting, or could use a Comparator for his solution. He claims he is using a third party library for which he needs Comparable objects.